# Adobe Air file run-time permission rejection doesn't dispatch an event

Tags: android, actionscript-3, permissions, actionscript, air

I'm using the relatively new Adobe Air run-time permissions for Android, to make use of the file system.

The problem is that when the user refuses to give permission which is essential, I would like to ask him again, yet the event handler is not being called upon rejection.

```
file.addEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS, function(e:PermissionEvent):void {
                        // does not reach to this point if user declined permission request
                        if (e.status == PermissionStatus.GRANTED)
                        {
                            contRead();
                        }});

                    try {
                        file.requestPermission();
                    } catch(e:Error)
                    {
                        // another request is in progress
                        trace("REQUEST ERROR!!!");
                    }
```

How do I tackle it? Do you have a separate event handler?
I'm using Adobe Air 25.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate function, so it can be called multiple times whenever it's needed. Right now, in your code, it only exists once (when the evenListener is added).

Try something like this setup below :

```
file.addEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS, checkPermissions);

try 
{ file.requestPermission(); }
catch(e:Error)
{
    // another request is in progress
    trace( "REQUEST ERROR!!! : " + e.toString() );
}

function checkPermissions (e:PermissionEvent) : void 
{
    trace( "Status is : " + e.status.toString() );

    // does not reach to this point if user declined permission request
    if (e.status == PermissionStatus.GRANTED)
    { contRead(); }
}
```

Comment: This won't help the OP, unless you think that the reason for the behavior they're reporting is that the function got garbage collected before the event fired.  I don't see anything to indicate that this is the case; the anonymous listener is a variable held by the file object in the OP's code, so it will persist as long as the file object does.

Comment: It doesn't help since it doesn't not trigger the event in case the user has declined the request.